# Facebook Graph API. How to get data from public page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Sorry for my English.

There is needed to get email, site link, phone number, instagram link, country and city from each page returned from search request. I don't know why, but /{page-id} and /{page-id}?fields={field_name} requests don't return any fields besides 'id'.

How can I get this info by Graph API when I know id of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the `fields` you need in your request. Otherwise you only get a very lightweight page object ;)

In general Facebook sends the `id` and some `name` (depending on the object) although there are much more fields in the requested object. This is done, because especially on mobile devices the bandwidth is important and these objects are very small. But as developer you can add some more fields to your request and add the mentioned `fields` query parameter.

You can then add a comma separated list with all the fields of the requested object. The returned JSON contains all these fields. But you have to be careful, because asking for a field that is not part of an object leads to a request error. So check the Facebook reference for the fields.

Next step for checking why you don't get the fields are possible missing permissions. You can only ask for fields that are public (in sense of public for the API, not necessarily the Facebook page) or you have some special permissions for.

*For pages you don't own you need the "Page Public Metadata Access" feature enabled for your access token. Otherwise you don't get any further information for this page.*
This is not required for pages you are the admin of.

For more details about the fields topic check the *Reading/Choosing Fields* section here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Comment: can you elaborate, why?

Comment: Please explain the solution with an example, not refer to Facebook references. If the sources gave a clear explanation, there would be no problem to ask here.

Comment: @henrry I think the explanation is better, now, if you think more information is needed, let me know